# Why do I get a 403 error when I tried to open a website?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-cloudfront

I tried to go to [capterra.com], but I get this error:

403 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: gl_jhiv6CXIVdD-qAeFEQXy9ymYLGqqXOR5MOKQI3Jpu2dlQk4tWIw==

What should I do?

Comment: Error 403 indicates forbidden access. It means that the server understands your request but does not want to fulfill it. As it currently stands, there is not enough detail in your question to answer exactly why you are being rejected access, but it usually happens because of faulty security plugin, a corrupt .htaccess file, or incorrect file permissions on server.

Comment: Also, I visited the said website successfully, so there is no problem with the website's servers. The problem can only be in your browser settings, or the way you are trying to access it. Some websites block access due to spam. webscrapping, bots etc.